# dropmenu overflow without expanding banner image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to create drop down list without expanding banner image.I want to show dropdown image next below the header for meadiaquery. now problem with positioning the mobileMenu div

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".mobileMenuImg").click(function(){
        $(".MobileItem").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

```css
/*banner*/
.banner{
  background-image: url("../image/banner-image.jpg");
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:100% 100%;
   text-align: center;
  
}
.banner-heading{
 margin-top:25px;
 font: bold 31px  roboto !important;
    color:#fff;  
 width:auto;
 text-align:center;
 
}
.banner-content{
 
 font: bold 50px  roboto !important;
    color:#fff; width:auto;
 
 text-align:center;
}
.banner-heading span,.banner-content span{
 background-color:#99408c;
 padding:0 10px;
}
.image-banner p{
 font: bold 20px roboto !important;
}
/*banner menu*/
.header{
 background-color:black;
 opacity:.7;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 width:100%;
 margin-bottom: 26px ;
 z-index:1000;
 
}
.logoImg img{
/*margin:10px 0 10px 0; */
float:right;
z-index:999;
}
.menu-item{margin:0;}
.menu{
 margin-top:10px;

}
 .menu ul{
  list-style-type:none;
  float: left;
 width: 100%;
 padding:0;
 }
 .menu ul li{
  display:inline-block;
      padding: 1% 8% 0 0%;
}
.menu ul li img{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.menu ul li a{
 padding:2% 5%; 
 font:bold 15px  roboto !important;
 color:#ffffff;
}
.menu ul li a:hover{
 color:#ffffff;
 text-decoration:none;
 cursor:pointer;
}

.mobileMenu{
 display:none;
}
.MobileItem{
  display:none;
  background:black;
  opacity:0.7;
 }
.MobileItem ul{
  list-style-type:none;
  margin-top:2%;
 }
 .mobileMenu-item li{
  text-align:left;
 }
 .mobileMenu-item li img{
  padding-right:2%;
 }
 .mobileMenu-item li a{
  color:#ffffff;
 }
 .mobileMenu-item li a:hover{
  color:#ffffff;
  text-decoration:none;
  cursor:pointer;
 }
 
/*End of banner menu*/

/*banner process icon*/
.banner-icon img{
  margin: 0% auto;
}
.image-banner,.image-bannerArrow{
 display:inline-block;
}

.image-banner{
 margin:5% 0 7% 0;
}
.image-banner p{
 margin-top:9%;
}
.image-bannerArrow{
 margin:9% 0 0% 0;
}
.image-banner p{
 color:#ffffff;
 font:bold 18px roboto !important;
 
}


/*End of banner process icon*/

/*order button*/
.orderButton{
 box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffa200;
 background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffa200), color-stop(1, #ffa200));
 background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffa200 5%, #ffa200 100%);
 background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffa200 5%, #ffa200 100%);
 background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #ffa200 5%, #ffa200 100%);
 background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffa200 5%, #ffa200 100%);
 background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffa200 5%, #ffa200 100%);
 background-color:#ffa200;
 border:1px solid #ffa200;
 display:inline-block;
 font:bold 30px roboto !important; 
 margin: 0px auto;
 margin-bottom:5%; 
 cursor:pointer;
 color:#ffffff;
 padding:.5% 3%;
}


     /*End of order button*/
  
/*End of banner*/ 
@media (min-width:250px) and (max-width:450px) 
{
 .logoImg img{
  float:none;
  padding:2% 1%;
 }
 .menu{
  display:none
 }
 .mobileMenu{
  display:block;
 }
 
 .mobileMenu img{
  max-width:50px;
  float:right;
  padding:2% 3% 2% 0;
  
 }
 .image-banner p{
 color:#ffffff;
 font:bold 10px roboto !important;
 }
 .banner-heading{
  font: bold 15px  roboto !important;
 }
 .banner-content{
 font: bold 15px  roboto !important;
    }
 .orderButton{
   font:bold 18px roboto !important; 
   
 }
 .image-banner{
 margin:0;
    }
  .image-bannerArrow{
 
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
  }
}
@media (min-width:451px) and (max-width:950px) {
 .logoImg img{
  float:none;
  padding:2% 1%;
 }
 .menu{
  display:none
 }
 .mobileMenu{
  display:block;
 }
 .mobileMenu img{
  max-width:50px;
  float:right;
  padding:6% 3% 2% 0;
  padding:0;
  
 }
 
 .image-banner p{
 color:#ffffff;
 font:bold 14px roboto !important;
 } 
 .banner-heading{
  font: bold 20px  roboto !important;
 }
 .banner-content{
 font: bold 22px  roboto !important;
    }
 .orderButton{
  font: bold 20px  roboto !important;
 }
 .image-banner{
 margin:0;
 
    }
  
}
@media (min-width:951px){
 .MobileItem{
  display:none !important;
 }
  
}
@media (min-width:250px)and (max-width:390px)
{
 .MobileItem{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:999;
     top:52px;
  
 }
}
@media (min-width:391px)and (max-width:500px)
{
 .MobileItem{
  position:relative !important;
  z-index:999;
        top: 0px;
  
 }
 .MobileItem ul{
  margin-top:5%;
 }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row banner">
    <!--  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">-->
     <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 header" >
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-5 logoImg" >
              <img src="image/gama-logo.png" alt="logo" class="img-responsive ">     
   </div> 
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 menu" >
       <ul class="menu-item">
       <li><a><img src="image/menu-icon.png" alt=""><p>Menu</p></a></li>
       <li><a><img src="image/byov.png" alt=""><p>What is BYOV?</p></a></li>
       <li><a><img src="image/pickup-icon.png" alt=""><p>Pick-up Points</p></a></li>
       <li><a><img src="image/catering-icon.png" alt=""><p>Catering</p></a></li>
       <li><a><img src="image/outlet-icon.png" alt=""><p>Nearest Outlet</p></a></li>
    </ul>
     </div> 
     <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-7 mobileMenu">
       <img src="image/menuColapse.png" alt="MobileMenuIcon" class="img-responsive mobileMenuImg"> 
     </div>
   </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 MobileItem">
      <ul class="mobileMenu-item">
       <li><a><img src="image/menu-icon.png" alt="">Menu</a></li>
       <li><a><img src="image/byov.png" alt="">What is BYOV?</a></li>
       <li><a><img src="image/pickup-icon.png" alt="">Pick-up Points</a></li>
       <li><a><img src="image/catering-icon.png" alt="">Catering</a></li>
       <li><a><img src="image/outlet-icon.png" alt="">Nearest Outlet</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <p class="banner-heading"><spanorder</span></p>
     <P class="banner-content"><span>STEPS </span></P>
    </div> 
   <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 banner-icon">
   
     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 image-banner" >
       <img src="image/pickup.png" alt="pickup point location" class="img-responsive"> 
    <p>PICK-UP POINT</p>
     </div>
      <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 image-bannerArrow">
       <img src="image/arrow.png" alt="next step" class="img-responsive"> 
    <p></p>
     </div>    
     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 image-banner">
       <img src="image/select-food.png" alt="food selection" class="img-responsive">  
    <p>SELECT FOOD</p>
     </div> 
     <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 image-bannerArrow">
      <img src="image/arrow.png" alt="next step" class="img-responsive"> 
      <p>.</p>
     </div>  
     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3  col-xs-3 image-banner">
       <img src="image/pay-online.png" alt="payment process" class="img-responsive">
    <p>PAY</p>
     </div>
     <div class=" col-xs-1">
     </div>
   </div> 
   <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <!-- <p class="banner-button"> -->
    <form method="post">
    
      <input type="submit" name="register" value="LET ME ORDER" class="orderButton">
    
      </form>
    <!-- </p>-->
    </div>
   
  <!-- </div> -->
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just add below css to your css code. Hope this is what you want.

---

`.MobileItem{
  position:absolute!important;
  margin-top:3rem;
}`